# How to pivot on more than one column for a spark dataframe?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

How can we pivot on more than one column in a dataframe.
e.g. The example mentioned here,
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-pivot.html

```
SELECT * FROM person
    PIVOT (
        SUM(age) AS a, AVG(class) AS c
        FOR (name, age) IN (('John', 30) AS c1, ('Mike', 40) AS c2)
    );
```

Here Pivot is done on (name,age).
We can't pass more than one parameter in Spark scala's pivot method as it only expects one column name as parameter.
How can we do the similar operation for a dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an array column to `pivot`:

```scala
val df2 = df.groupBy("id","address")
            .pivot(array("name","age"), 
                   Seq(array(lit("John"),lit("30")).as("c1"), 
                       array(lit("Mike"),lit("40")).as("c2")))
            .agg(sum('age).as("a"), avg('class).as("c"))

df2.show
+---+-------+----+----+----+----+
| id|address|c1_a|c1_c|c2_a|c2_c|
+---+-------+----+----+----+----+
|200|Street2|null|null|null|null|
|100|Street1|30.0| 1.0|null|null|
|400|Street4|null|null|null|null|
|300|Street3|null|null|null|null|
+---+-------+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am trying to run a similar query.

project1.groupBy("mgr").pivot(array("job","deptno"), Seq(array(lit("MANAGER"),lit("20")).as("c10"), array(lit("CLERK"),lit("10")).as("m20"))).agg(sum(project1.col("sal")).alias("ss"), count("*").alias("c")).show

And getting this error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.Column array(MANAGER, 20) AS `c10`"
Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: @Ashutosh It would be more appropriate to open another question, as there is not enough details and no sample dataframe. please include the necessary details in the new question, thanks

Comment: Your answer has helped me a lot.
Regarding my last comment lit() was not working for me it seems. I tried using withColumn() to concat two columns and passed it in pivot. It worked.
project1.withColumn("p", concat($"job", $"deptno")).groupBy("mgr").pivot("p").agg(sum(project1.col("salary")).alias("ss"), count("*").alias("c")).show